# Geometry Nodes: How to check distance along specific axis (with geometry proximity node)?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I instanced spheres on faces with a green material.
I would like to delete the spheres that protrude out of these areas (the ones on the border to the grey areas basically).
My nodetree uses geometry proximity to delete spheres as soon as they contain a face with a certain distance to the green stripes. But this checks for distance in all directions effectively deleting spheres sorted by their size which i dont want... instead **how can i restrict the distance check to be only in the x direction?**

I tried `position node->seperate xyz->only x->combine xyz->source position` (geometry proximity node), but that didnt do anything so i dont know where else to input that axis information.

[image]

Picture 1: The maximum amount of spheres.
[image]

Picture 2: I want to delete the spheres that protrude into the grey areas. But since the distance to the green areas is checked in all directions it also deletes all the big spheres. I just want my forest to be contained in the green area^^
[image]

Comment: The position must be restricted to X axis not only for the source, but also for the target. That's why your attempt affecting only the source does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Instead of relying on the distance in (X,Y,Z) space, only the projection along X of the vector connecting the actual face centre (*Position* node) to the nearest face centre (*Position* socket of the *Geometry Proximity* node) is compared by the *Less Than* node to the user defined threshold. This distance is computed by the four nodes outside of the frame *delete trees based on distance* to identify the modification.

[image: GN Graph]

**Resources:** [image]